# create checkbox with customise label in symfony

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, symfony

I have a simply problem. 
I want just to create a checkbox widget with symfony so:

```
 $builder->add("terms", CheckboxType::class, array('label'=>false));
```

But i obtain this output:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_terms" class="required">
        <input id="fos_user_registration_form_terms" name="fos_user_registration_form[terms]" required="required" class=" checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
                        Terms
     </label>
</div>
```

I want change text of label but when override the label attribut in PHP the output is:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_terms" class="required">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_terms" class="required required">
              <input id="fos_user_registration_form_terms" name="fos_user_registration_form[terms]" required="required" class=" checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
                        test
             </label>
        </div>
        test
     </label>
</div>
```

I have two label.

I will want obtain:

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_terms" class="required">
    <input id="fos_user_registration_form_terms" name="fos_user_registration_form[terms]" required="required" class=" checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
                My label for accept terms with <a> tag   

 </label>
```

I use this [bundle](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html) (BraincraftedBootstrapBundle)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to modify form template http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: @dragoste you beat me to it! :D

Comment: Also http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Because you use `$builder->add("terms",` Symfony defaults to use the quoted string in the add method; in your case "terms", and capitalizes the first letter. Question for you: Is the label you want to use in a file? Above you show with an <a> tag. Do you want to show a large amount of HTML text?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers i want juste to link to my CGV page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render form like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_terms" class="required">
    {{form_widget(form.terms)}}
    My label for accept terms with 
    <a> tag   </a>

 </label>
</div>
```

Just render form widget and create label by hand.

Comment: It's Ok but the documentation of symfony say this:  "When you use the Bootstrap form themes and render the fields manually, calling form_label() for a checkbox/radio field doesn't show anything. Due to Bootstrap internals, the label is already shown by form_widget()."